# PostgreSQL настройки после установки

Tags: postgresql

Установил PostgreSQL, workbench запускается все хорошо.
Но в командной строке не выполняются команды pg_restore... Видимо нужно прописать переменные среды. Не подскажите какой указать пусть к какой папке.

Comment: `SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin` впрочем он запускается и без PATH `D:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\pg_restore ...`

Comment: @Sergey спасибо, помогло